# Question Array Output for Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So here is my question and i need some help.

here is my array output

```
[TransactionDetails] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionId] => 60089978
            [TransactionDate] => 2021-10-20T12:43:24.413
            [Product] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => IdentiFraud Consumer+
                            [version] => 2.2.0
                        )

                )
```

This is what i am using to call it from an xml reply...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// Debug output of the response
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
 
$objXmlDocument = simplexml_load_string($response);
 
if ($objXmlDocument === FALSE) {
    echo "There were errors parsing the XML file.\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo $error->message;
    }
    exit;
}
 
$objJsonDocument = json_encode($objXmlDocument);
$arrOutput = json_decode($objJsonDocument);
```

I have tried....

```
$arrOutput['TransactionDetails']['TransactionID']
$arrOutput['TransactionDetails']->TransactionID
```

And about every iteration there of.
I have tried with the Json_decode both true and false no joy....

Please Help what i am not doing right ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the lines using `json_encode` and `json_decode`
2. Read [the SimpleXML examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)
3. Don't look at the `var_dump` output, look at the actual XML (`$response`)
4. Access the data you need directly from `$objXmlDocument` based on what's in that XML

For instance, if `$response` looks like this:

```xml
<TransactionDetails>
    <TransactionId>60089978</TransactionId>
</TransactionDetails>
```

Then the `$objXmlDocument` represents the `<TransactionDetails>` tag, and to get the value in the `<TransactionId>` tag you would write this:

```php
echo $objXmlDocument->TransactionId;
```

Comment: I will take a look at the manual Thanks For Your Help

Comment: so what finally worked for me was ``` $arrOutput->TransactionDetails->TransactionId```

Comment: @matthewparisi Based on that variable name, it sounds like you're still using the json_encode and json_decode lines. Please don't, I promise you're better off without them.

Comment: @matthewparisi Try using `$objXmlDocument->TransactionDetails->TransactionId` instead